# "cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, object-oriented-database

I have a C_table and M_table and there is a m to 1 relationship between C_table and M_table, also I have L_table which Is A C_table type, , I'm trying to use OODBMS using oracle SQL Developer. I have the following types and tables:

```
create type C_table as object
(
  se number(10), 
  sp number(10), 
  pr number(15), 
  me number(3), 
  ste S_type, 
  name ref M_type
)not final;


create type m_type as object
(
  name varchar2(25), 
  add varchar(25)
);

type L_type under computer_type
(
  w number(5)
);
```

and I have created their tables, as well, now I'm trying to insert into thhe L_table as follow and I'm getting the following error:

```
insert into l_tab select 500,2,1600,4, S_type('Ms','Me'), REF(d),1.5 from m_tab d where 
d.name= 'Int';

SQL Error: ORA-22979: cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF
22979. 00000 -  "cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF"
*Cause:    Attempt to insert an object view REF or user-defined REF in a
           REF column created to store system generated REF values"
*Action:   Make sure the REF to be inserted is not from an object view
           or from a user-defined REF column
```

Comment: can you provide a full script that causes the error? because [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9cb4/8) workes for me (on 11g)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't load the full script because of the confidential rights. But I'm happy to share the solution to this problem.

```
create type C_table as object
(
  se number(10), 
  sp number(10), 
  pr number(15), 
  me number(3), 
  ste S_type, 
  name ref M_type
 )not final;


 create type m_type as object
 (
     name varchar2(25), 
     add varchar(25)
 );

 type L_type under computer_type
 (
   w number(5)
 );
```

Based on ERD we have already knew that L_type Is-A C_type, and we know C_type has a reference to M_type. When I created the table out of these types, I did't know I have to define a foreign key from M_table in L_table as well, and I was thinking since L_table derived from C_table, if I define the foreign key in the C_table is enough, but it was not enough and I had to define a foreign key from M_table in L_table as well like this

```
create table C_table of C_type
(foreign key (name) references M_table) 
object id primary key
```

and also :

```
create table l_table of l_type
(foreign key (name) references M_table) 
object id primary key
```

now if I use this query I won't have any problem or error:

```
insert into l_tab select 500,2,1600,4, S_type('Ms','Me'), REF(d),1.5 from m_tab d where 
d.name= 'Int';
```

also I read in some blogs that we have to be careful to don't use system names, and predefined name as an attribute in a table, like in this example I used name in M_table, which is not a good way,  so finally I changed it to M_name instead of name.